# File upload missing Path Attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

I have scoured the web looking for an answer to this, but I've had no luck.

I want to upload a file to a server running Node JS and save the file in an arbitrary folder server-side.

Everything seems to work just fine.

My client POST code (using drag and drop):

```
var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(files));
```

Server-side POST handler:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    require('fs').rename(
        req.body.path,
        '/uploads' + serverPath,
        function(error) {
            if (error) {
                res.send({
                    error: 'Something bad happened!'
                });
                return;
            }

            res.send({
                path: serverPath
            });
        }
    );
});
```

But the server-side code fails. Why? Well, the answer is simple. In most of the use cases I've seen, the file `path` attribute is read in. The POST request I am sending to the server looks something like this:

```
{
    webkitRelativePath: '',
    lastModified: 1429402697000,
    lastModifiedDate: '2015-04-19T00:18:17.000Z',
    name: 'sample.zip',
    type: 'application/zip',
    size: 317256
}
```

I can't get Chrome on Mac to make a `path` attribute. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code at client side

```
 <form  name="myform" data-validate="parsley" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://<host>:<port number>/upload" target="upload">
 <input id="uploadImage" type="file" style="display:none" name="myFile" />
 <br/>  
 <a onclick="$('input[id=uploadImage]').click();">Select File</a>

   <input type="submit" id="submit_button"  value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

use following code at server side

install these modules and use as follows

```
  var multiparty = require('multiparty');
  var http = require('http')
  var util = require('util')
 var form = new multiparty.Form();
 form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        var fs = require('fs');
        fs.readFile(files.myFile[0].ws.path, function (err, data) {
             console.log("File data"+data);
             console.log("FileName--->"+files.myFile[0].ws.path);
        });

 });
```

in above code you can get file name with ---> files.myFile[0].ws.path

and  file get data with ----->  data